# limiting the number of time .live() function become active in javascript

Tags: javascript, live

I have a javascript that has a live function as:

```
$('.myid').live('click', function () {
            $.jGrowl("<strong style='color: yellow;'>Hello</strong><p>The message is so and so</p>", {'life': 5000});
                  })
```

now whenever I click its related link having class as "myid" a Box pops up and shows the message.
Now the problem is if the previous box is still active and I click on the "myid" link again I once again get a pop up just below the previous one. As many number of time I click the link that many number of time I get the pop up.
I want that only one popup should be visible at a time.
Please help.

Comment: *"now whenever I click its related link having id as "myid" a Box pops up and shows the message. "* That's surprising, as you're using a *class* selector, not an *id* selector.

Comment: Sounds like you want the "pop up" to be modal, so the user has to dismiss it before invoking another one (or before doing anything on the page, really).  Does `jGrown` have an option for that?

Comment: sorry my mistake.. yes the class name is myid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jGrowl doesn't seem to offer the option of making the notification modal (which isn't surprising), but you an use the `beforeClose` or `close` callback on the jGrowl instance ([see the documentation](https://github.com/stanlemon/jGrowl) for details on those) and a flag:

```
var warningOpen = false;
$('.myid').live('click', function () {
    if (!warningOpen) {
        warningOpen = true;
        $.jGrowl("<strong style='color: yellow;'>Hello</strong><p>The message is so and so</p>", {
            'life': 5000,
            'close': function() {
                warningOpen = false;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

If you want to make it specific to the specific element that was clicked, you could do that with `data`.

---

Note that `live` was deprecated years ago and removed a few versions back. Use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) in today's world.

Comment: David @ the pop is visible for 5 seconds only. and user do not have to dismiss it. Its just that I want if one pop up is active no other popup should be active just below it